# How can I send out messages when clicking on specific images using if/else-statements?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm trying to code such that if the user clicks on certain image, then the user gets a message that describes the picture. The picture will also get larger. That's why I want send out messages to describe the picture if the person doesn't understand the picture. I'm new to javascript so I just try to keep it simple. This is my code below. Can you tell where I did wrong? (By the way, the text's in swedish).

```
function resizeImage(image) {
   image.style.width = "70%";
   image.style.height = "auto";
   if (image == document.getElementById("#code-picture")) {
      window.alert("En bild på programmeringskod!" + "\n\nStarta om sidan för att återfå  bilden av normalstorlek.");
   } else if (image == document.getElementById("#electronics-picture")) {
    window.alert("En bild på kretskort!" + "\n\nStarta om sidan för att återfå bilden av normalstorlek.");
   }
}
```

One of the two pictures in the HTML

```
<img src="images/code.jpg" alt="En bild som visar programmeringskod" id="code-picture" onclick="resizeImage(this)"/>
```

Comment: Is any part of it working? Can you show us the html of one of your images?

Comment: Yes, I can. Let me just edit.

Comment: Try `document.getElementById("code-picture")` or `image.id === 'code-picture'` both should work

Comment: Thanks. The first one worked. The other didn't.

Answer (score 1):

It should be document.getElementbyId("code-picture") but not

document.getElementbyId("#code-picture"). //this is wrong

document.getElementbyId(id) takes only the id of element to be targeted. You should not add a # before it.(id should not include #)

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify this by adding the full message to either a data-description attribute or the alt parameter. For my example, I'm going to use the data-description attribute.

```js
function resizeImage(image) {
   image.style.width = "70%";
   image.style.height = "auto";
   let desc = image.getAttribute("data-description").replace("\\n","\n");
   window.alert(desc);
}
```

```html
<img src="images/code.jpg" data-description="En bild på programmeringskod!\nStarta om sidan för att återfå  bilden av normalstorlek." alt="En bild som visar programmeringskod" id="code-picture" onclick="resizeImage(this)"/>
```